# Toggling divs to fade in and out on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

## Problem

I have two info boxes that are `display:none` when a user clicks the first `span.highlight` shows info box to the side `aside.info`. If the other span is clicked it shows the alternate second info box. **However, clicking on the links a second time, doesn't fade them out/back in**

Previously, I didn't have a `fadeOut` function and instead had `bg-one` and `bg-two` fade in and out, but you would still see the previous element before the other faded in, **so I feel like the problem is with my if/else statement.**

## JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51haqmg3/4/ (scroll until you see two highlighted phrases)

### scripts.js

```
    /*-------------------------------------
    HIGHLIGHT
    --------------------------------------*/

    $(".highlight").click(function() {
       $(".highlight").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from spans
       $(".fa-plus-circle").show(); // Show the Font Awesome icon
       $(this).addClass("active");  // Add an active class to span just
       $(this).find(".fa-plus-circle").hide();
       $(this).data("clicked", true);

       var clicked = $(".highlight").data("clicked");

       if (clicked) {
        $(".bg-one").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".bg-two").fadeIn(500);
        });
       } else {
        $(".bg-two").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".bg-one").fadeIn(500);
        });
       }
   });
```

### index.html

```
<aside class="info bg-one">
        <div class="define">
            <p class="background">Background One</p>
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=21&txt=224%C3%97148&w=224&h=148" alt="">
            <p class="caption"></p>
            <p class="hoarding"></p>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, laudantium, excepturi. Neque doloribus praesentium ad. Voluptates animi accusamus iusto laborum aperiam quis, eveniet architecto mollitia labore in laboriosam illum. Facilis.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum perspiciatis minus corporis expedita fugiat excepturi nostrum atque adipisci magnam deserunt, reprehenderit, a fugit, neque esse unde mollitia at nemo. Natus?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quas nulla, voluptatem corrupti vel, maiores delectus fuga dolorum sint, nisi suscipit deleniti, velit? Debitis maxime, necessitatibus similique saepe vel nisi!</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.define -->
    </aside>
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect if the first element was clicked or if it was the second one and then fade out and fade in the corresponding info boxes you could do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/so14L57w/

All I changed was the bool variable to determine which background to switch to:

```
var fadeOne = $(".highlight").index(this) == 0;
```

This isn't a great solution though since it won't scale beyond your 2 elements.  However you could switch on the $(".highlight") index and load the correct background that way for more than 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're always setting them to true instead of toggling them on each click.

Fix this line:

```
$(this).data("clicked", true);
```

to something like:

```
$(this).data("clicked", !$(this).data("clicked"));
```

---

Also the whole block above it:

```
$(".highlight").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from spans
$(".fa-plus-circle").show(); // Show the Font Awesome icon
$(this).addClass("active");  // Add an active class to span just
$(this).find(".fa-plus-circle").hide();
```

should be in the conditional in order for you to be able to cancel their action when clicked is false.